# Get results from target page when returning to source page

Tags: windows-phone-7, navigation

My Windows Phone 7 app as a page with an edit form with a ListPicker control. One of the items in the list is "add new" which, when selected, opens another page with another edit form for adding a new lookup value. Problem is, page navigation is asynchronous, so when the source page navigates to the target page, code execution continues and I don't know how to get a notification from the target page when the user saves. I want the value they just added to be inserted and selected in the ListPicker on the source page. I'm not even sure how to look this up on Google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your first page you will need to override the `OnNavigatedTo` method (or attach a second event handler)

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e) {
  // Check for state
}
```

Your second page will need to write a piece of state into a location both pages can access, then the first page can see if this state exists.
A simple `Dictionary<string,object>` off the static App object can be a starting point for this sort of state.

Comment: Actually, I already had check value being set in the App object, but I was checking for state in the Loaded event -- a definite "duh" moment. Oh, and the fact I wasn't repopulating the ListPicker when a value was added.